# What does μ mean in law?

Tags: legal-terms

[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%CE%BCing) shows just one other use of μing by the same author. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter)#Use_as_symbol) evinces no use of μ in law or philosophy. But I read on  [Phi - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi) that

> In [philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy), φ is often used as shorthand for a [generic act](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Generic_act&action=edit&redlink=1). (Also in uppercase.).

Herring, [*Criminal Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (8 edn, 2018)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/criminal-law-9780198811817?cc=ca&lang=en&). p. 217

> **A. Simester, ‘Is Strict Liability Always Wrong?’** in A. Simester (ed.) Appraising
>   Strict Liability (Oxford: OUP, 2005), 33– 7
>
> ...
>
> > ### Objections Specific to Paradigm (Stigmatic) Crimes
> >
> > Suppose that the state were to create a crime of ‘homicide’, defined as a strict liability
> >     offence of causing death. Objections to crimes of this type depend, in turn, on the nature of
> >     the criminal law. Without dwelling on the familiar analysis, there seem to me to be certain
> >     paradigm features associated with the criminalization of **μing**. Ex ante, μing is prohibited
> >     and declared to be wrong: citizens are not merely requested but instructed not to. Ex post,
> >     where D is found to have transgressed, he is convicted of μing and liable to punishment
> >     which may be substantial, perhaps including imprisonment. The conviction and the punishment
> >     also express censure, to D, Y, and the public at large. As well as suffering hard
> >     treatment, D is labelled as a particular sort of criminal (a ‘**μer**’), a labelling that conveys a
> >     public implication of culpable wrongdoing.
> >           These paradigm features of the criminal law imply certain objections to making μing a strict
> >     liability crime, at least where strict liability leads to conviction of blameless defendants . . .

Comment: Appears to just be a variable that Simester frequently uses in his writing. μ was used there because φ was already used for something else previously. This is further evident by his repeated use of letters for people in the extract, as well as other texts he has written.